# индекс 0 в массиве после explode

Tags: php

Как привязать первому индексу 1 а не 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

много есть вариантов. один из них

```
$array = [1,2,3];
array_unshift($array, null);
unset($array[0]);

[ 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3]
```